# Python max( ) function incorrect when key has '%' sign as first character

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a set of data where some of the keys have percent signs as the first character.  Why does the max( ) function return the incorrect answer if a percent sign is the first character in a key?

```
>>> mdict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, '%c' : 4}
>>> max(mdict)
  'b'
```

Is there a way around this without remapping keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting the maximum *key* (by lexographical order). `max()` looks at the keys only, **not** the values, unless you tell it to with a `key` function. `%c` sorts before `a` or `b`, so the maximum key is `b`:

```
>>> max({'a': 100, 'b': 0, '%c': 50})
'b'
>>> min({'a': 100, 'b': 0, '%c': 50})
'%c'
```

If you expected the maximum value, use:

```
max(mdict, key=mdict.get)
```

Demo:

```
>>> mdict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, '%c' : 4}
>>> max(mdict, key=mdict.get)
'%c'
```